# Replacing a string across procedures in SQL Server

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2005

Is there a way to make a procedure to search and replace a specific string in all procedures?

Comment: A little more information please. Are you trying to search every field of every table or a particular field?

Comment: Im trying to replace a comment in the SQL stored procedure thats intefering with the software itself,  but there are way too many procedures to do it manually, one by one

Comment: So you are trying to bulk update stored procedure definitions then not user table contents?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Maybe it would be easier to fix the application. Why does the software care about comments? Does it also barf on extended properties?

Assuming the comment is always the same, run this in Management Studio with results to text:

```
SET NOCOUNT ON;

SELECT 'GO
    ' + REPLACE([definition], '/* offending comment */', '')
    FROM sys.sql_modules
    WHERE [definition] LIKE '%/* offending comment */%';
```

This will yield a series of `CREATE PROCEDURE` commands separated by `GO`. You can't necessarily do a search/create for `CREATE PROCEDURE` and change it to `ALTER` in case you have actual `CREATE PROCEDURE` strings within the stored procedure body. So instead you can pull these results into your favorite text editor and do a search and replace for:

```
GO
CREATE PROCEDURE
```

Replacing it with:

```
GO
ALTER PROCEDURE
```

(Though this assumes that you don't have comments *before* the `CREATE PROCEDURE` line. If you do, you'll need to get more creative with your search and replace.)

If you don't need to worry about procedures that contain a valid string `CREATE PROCEDURE` - and assuming that your syntax is actually `CREATE PROCEDURE` and not `CREATE PROC` or random spacing between `CREATE` and `PROC` and that your system isn't case sensitive and you used `create proc` or `Create Proc`...

```
SET NOCOUNT ON;

SELECT 'GO
    ' + REPLACE(REPLACE([definition], '/* offending comment */', ''),
    'CREATE PROCEDURE', 'ALTER PROCEDURE')
    FROM sys.sql_modules
    WHERE [definition] LIKE '%/* offending comment */%';
```

If you don't care about the existing tangible things associated with your stored procedures, e.g. permissions, you could also do it this way:

```
SELECT 'DROP PROCEDURE ' 
    + QUOTENAME(OBJECT_SCHEMA_NAME([object_id])) 
    + '.' + QUOTENAME(OBJECT_NAME([object_id])) + ';
    ' + 'GO
    ' + REPLACE([definition], '/* offending comment */', '')
FROM sys.sql_modules
WHERE [definition] LIKE '%/* offending comment */%';
```

This will generate a script that is much closer to ready to go, since it just drops the procedure and re-creates it (so doesn't need to change `CREATE` to `ALTER`), but it is not very common that you can just drop and re-create objects because of permissions and/or dependencies.

`CREATE OR REPLACE` or something similar in DDL would make this much easier to script out. If you feel this would be a valuable addition to SQL Server, please vote for the following suggestion (and add your use case, or why you think this would be valuable, to the comments):

http://connect.microsoft.com/SQLServer/feedback/details/127219/create-or-replace

Comment: Thanks a lot for ur explanation! About the comment interfering, its because amidst it theres a line that doesnt have / in it, and since we are talking about a huge amount of procedures and lines along them, it would take forever to do it manually.

Comment: Oh HECK YES! Thank you Aaron Bertrand for the very useful script. I had a set of stored procedures that ran "update statistics" on 2 tables, and I had to change them to say "update statistics with fullscan, columns". This (your 2nd one) did exactly what I wanted to do - generate ALTER scripts. Integrate with a "sp_MSforEachDB" loop and presto!

Comment: No, please DO NOT use sp_msforeachdb : https://sqlblog.org/blogs/aaron_bertrand/archive/2010/12/29/a-more-reliable-and-more-flexible-sp-msforeachdb.aspx

Answer (score 0):

How about Generating the Scripts of ALL those stored procedure as a .sql file and then replacing the comment in that generated file with the help of CTRL + H. Isn't that the easier option?

Comment: It might be, but if there are 5,000 procedures and only 150 of them contain the comment... so if you're going to limit it to the procedures that contain the comment (requiring a `WHERE` clause), why not also add the `REPLACE()` call before you get the output?

Comment: I definitely see your point. But if we generate it via the wizard the formatting of the script stays as-is. Whereas if we run our own query to fetch this i think the formatting would take a toss and I was wondering whether it might confuse the author. If all the comments are at the beginning of the SP it should be fine but what if we want to replace the comments of a particular code block within that SP?

Comment: Why would the formatting "take a toss"? Maybe if you use results to grid, but results to text should be accurate (as long as none of the procedures are longer than the max text output). As for the type of comment and where the comment is in the procedure body, that shouldn't matter either, though we have no idea about either due to lack of detail in the question.

Comment: Yeah I was talking about results to grid.

Comment: Notice in my answer one of the first things I say is "results to text"... :-)

Comment: oh sorry abt that. My bad i didn't notice it properly :(